# social login through Instragram & Twitter in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, social-authentication

I am working on angular6 project. How to allow the users to login through Intragram & twitter?

I have implemented google & facebook login but I don't know how to implement through Instragram & twitter.

Comment: Can you please share more details about your project is a web or mobile application?